# How to update fields automatically

Tags: couchdb

In my CouchDB database I'd like all documents to have an 'updated_at' timestamp added when they're changed (and have this enforced).

- I can't modify the document with `validation` functions
- `updates` functions won't run unless they're called specifically (so it'd be possible to update the document and not call the specific update function)

How should I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this now without triggering `_update` handlers. This is nice idea to track documents changing time, but it faces problems with replications.

Replications are working on top of public API and this means that:

1. In case of enforcing such trigger you'll have replications broken since it will be impossible to sync data as it is without document modification. Since document get modified, he receives new revision which may easily lead to dead loop if you replicate data from database A to B and B to A in continuous mode.
2. In other case when replications are fixed there will be always way to workaround your trigger.

Comment: It's a shame there's no way to get the replications saving data as a user who is exempt from the auto-updating, as this would fix the replication issue. But still there'd need to be a couchdb facility to update fields on update. It's dirty but I think I'll do a validation on the delivered update to reject unless the delivered `updated_at` time is within <acceptable clock difference> from now (so long as the user isn't the replicating user). It's ugly, but it'll get the job done!

Comment: Feel free to [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB) about (:

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest one work around - you can create a view which emits a current date as a key (or a part of it):

```
function( doc ){
  emit( new Date, null );
}
```

This will assign current dates to all documents as soon as the view generation gets triggered (which happens after first request to it) and will reassign new dates on each update of a specific document.

Although the above should solve your issue, I would advice against using it for the reasons already explained by *Kxepal*: if you're on a replicated network, each node will assign its own dates. So taking this into account, the best I can recommend is to solve the issue on the client side and just post the documents with a date already embedded.